# Get data using variable from query string?

Tags: php, mysql, query-string

I hope the title I used here was understandable...

I have a database with two columns: ward_id and ward_name.

I wish to create dynamic pages for each ward and have the ward_name show in the page title. I have created a header.php file which I am including.

I am passing the id through the URL using ....?wid={$row['ward_id']} which is working fine when I create other queries that use that id to get data from the database.

However the problem I am having is that the page refuses to display the ward_name as the page title. I expected something like this to work:

```
    $wardid = $_GET['wid'];

    $query = "SELECT ward_name, ward_id FROM wards WHERE ward_id=$wardid";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
$pagetitle = "$row['ward_name']";
    }
```

But it doesn't, I have tried so many variations on the above I can't possibly remember them all now so I really hope someone can help me... Here is the code as it currently stands:

Header Page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?php echo $pagetitle; ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="wholepage">

            <div class="headlinewrapper">
                <div class="headline">
                    <h1></h1>
                    <h2></h2>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="headlinesidewrapper">
                <div class="headlineside">
                    <p>shv jsfj sjnsf jnsf nsnf nj njsfn
njfjn sfns njf njnsf njs dgbjn dn jnd njjn dd d d nj njd njnd njd nn djndj njd</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="topnavigation">
                <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="boroughs.php">Boroughs</a></li>
                <li><a href="wards.php">Wards</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="sidebar">

            </div>

            <div class="mainpagewrapper">
```

Dynamic page:

```
<?php

    $pagetitle = "Hello";
    include ('header.php');

    ?>

                <div class="mainpage">
                    <div class="infobox">

                    </div>
    <?php

    require('mysqli_connect.php');

    mysql_select_db('onetwom2_london');


    $wardid = $_GET['wid'];

    $query = "SELECT ward_name, ward_id FROM wards WHERE ward_id=$wardid";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<div class=\"boroughlist\"><p>{$row['ward_name']}</p></div>" ;
    }

    $pagetitle = $result;

    ?>

    <div class="clear">
    </div>      
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </body>

    </html>
```

So I just want to know how/if it is possible to match the id passed through the URL to the ward_id stored on the database and then have the page title display the ward_name linked to that id. I apologise if this is a really easy question, I have spent hours trying to work this out and I am completely stumped! (the code I posted above is just the end result of 5 hours of frustration so please appreciate I have tried hard before asking you for help :) )

Comment: You don't need to wrap the value in (double) quotes. Try changing `$pagetitle = "$row['ward_name']";` to `$pagetitle = $row['ward_name'];`.

Comment: Hi Markus I have tried what you suggested but no luck, Im actually hoping that somebody might have a go at rewriting the code I have posted as I have triedso many variations that my head is spinning.

Comment: You also don't need a `while()` loop to fetch what should be a single value in the database. Using while suggests that there could be MULTIPLE ward_id's in the database.

Comment: @MWells Ok, I'll update my answer with _rewritten code_ asap.

Comment: use PDO forget the mysql extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should step through the problem to see where it goes awry, var-dump $pagetitle in the while loop. See what is being stored if it comes out as NULL you are not retrieving anything from the DB and there is an issue with either Query. if it has the correct variable the problem is with your PHP. Var_dump $pagetitle in your header.php file to be sure it is getting the correct variable.

Let me know the outcome and I can help you from there

```
<?php
    $wardid = $_GET['wid'];
    $query = "SELECT ward_name, ward_id FROM wards WHERE ward_id=$wardid";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $pagetitle = "$row['ward_name']";
        //Step Through The Problem
        var_dump($pagetitle);
    }
    include ('header.php');
?>
<div class="mainpage">
  <div class="infobox">
   </div>
  <?php
    require('mysqli_connect.php');
    mysql_select_db('onetwom2_london');
    $wardid = $_GET['wid'];
    $query = "SELECT ward_name, ward_id FROM wards WHERE ward_id=$wardid";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
       echo "<div class=\"boroughlist\"><p>{$row['ward_name']}</p></div>" ;
    }
    $pagetitle = $result;
  ?>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>      
</div>
```

UPDATED - Try This

```
<?php
    require('mysqli_connect.php');
    mysql_select_db('onetwom2_london');
    $wardid = $_GET['wid'];
    $query = "SELECT ward_name, ward_id FROM wards WHERE ward_id=$wardid";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $pagetitle = $row['ward_name'];
        //Step Through The Problem
        var_dump($pagetitle);
    }
    include ('header.php');
?>
<div class="mainpage">
  <div class="infobox">
   </div>
  <?php
    $result2 = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {
       echo "<div class=\"boroughlist\"><p>{$row2['ward_name']}</p></div>" ;
    }
  ?>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: Hi wmfrancia, I have revised my code and added it to your answer (but now i think that was the wrong thing to do :/) Currently the page is displaying the correct ward_name value in the body of the page but the pagetitle is displaying the value: mysqli_connect

Comment: Hi again, thanks for your efforts. I tried the code exactly as above and the page displayed the correct ward_name in the body but the pagetitle was just the website address ( eg blahblahblah.co.uk) I then added require('mysqli_connect.php'); mysql_select_db('onetwom2_london'); after the first <?php tag and the pagetitle changed to mysqli_connect . It just refuses to access the database and use the ward_name for the pagetitle some reason..., but works just fine for anything else.

Comment: hmmm, i removed some redundancy in the code, it looks like something is off with your mySql code. try converting everything to MySqli instead

Comment: Yeah, it seems strange that its not working, to my (inexperienced) eye this code doesnt seem particularly complex... Just as a last ditch effort could the problem be at all with the header.php or the positioning when I include it in the dynamic page?

Comment: Hi wmfrancia I have marked your answer as correct as your code was spot on. The problem was with a file I was including that had a page title already assigned that was overriding my variable :/ A very amateur mistake I know but I have learnt a lot from this by listening to all the answers here so thank you very much for putting in the effort to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor and use some ORM or library that gives you parameterized queries.

This code opens you right up for SQL-injection attacks:

```
$wardid = $_GET['wid'];

$query = "SELECT ward_name, ward_id FROM wards WHERE ward_id=$wardid";
```

Comment: Hi Dan, I will do, but is what I am trying to do even possible? I feel that if I can't get this right I should not be trying anything else possibly more advanced.

Comment: What do you mean with $pagetitle = $result;

Comment: Hi Momo, I was just using that to get across the gist of what I am trying to achieve. I want to display the ward_name from the database as the page title. The code above is very much not working so I am looking for suggestions on how this is possible to do, if necessary rewriting as much of the code above as is required.

Comment: This is not an answer. It should be a comment.

Comment: @MarcB: Oh yeah? You try sticking all that info in a comment and you'll see how readable it is.

Comment: @MWells: Yes it's possible. To find out what's going wrong echo your query and do a print_r on the result.

Comment: @dan: no need to repeat the bad code. just link to the usual bobby-tables type places in a comment.

Comment: @MarcB: That isn't just bad code. It's huge security hole. It warrants an answer IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

**First of all,** *avoid using double quotes* as much as possible. Use single `'` quotes instead. Double quotes makes php look for variables in the string which will be parsed. Using single quotes, any variables in the string will be echo'd as plain text, increasing overall performance.

So,

instead of

```
$pagetitle = "$row['ward_name']";
```

you want to use

```
$pagetitle = $row['ward_name'];
```

The same here:

```
echo "<div class=\"boroughlist\"><p>{$row['ward_name']}</p></div>";
```

should be changed into:

```
echo '<div class="boroughlist"><p>'.$row['ward_name'].'</p></div>';
```

Using single quotes makes `\"` also obsolete, making the code more readable and it'll be easier to write.

**For working with databases** in PHP I recommend you to work with a MySQLi Class. Have a look at https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class . It's easy to implement and the learning curve is low.

[MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) is the successor of MySQL (which is deprecated by now). With MySQLi [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) got introduced which make your queries containing (user) input save against [*SQL Injection*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) would be even better, but it's harder to use.

**Regarding** `$wardid = $_GET['wid'];`: Make sure the value is being interpreted as integer. So try this:

```
$wardid = (int) $_GET['wid']; // type cast to integer aka Type Juggling
$query  = 'SELECT ward_name, ward_id FROM wards WHERE ward_id=`'.$wardid.'` LIMIT 1';
```

Notice the `LIMIT 1`. This limits the query to one result, making it perform better as it stops right after it has found a result.

*Good luck on your way learning more about SQL and PHP :-)*

---

### Edit:

According to [*a comment from the questioner*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195845/using-php-and-id-passed-through-url-assigning-a-variable-page-title-a-value-from/18196252#comment26665962_18195845), I want to add a *rewritten example* of the code given in the question:

```
<?php

    // I'll demonstrate how to use the MySQLi Class
    require_once('mysqlidb.php');

    // Connect to the database
    $db = new Mysqlidb('host', 'username', 'password', 'databaseName');

    // Get the wid from the uri
    $wardid = $_GET['wid'];

    // Fetch the page title from the db
    $result    = $db->where('ward_id', $wardid)->get('wards', 1);
    $pagetitle = $result['ward_name'];

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <!-- A templating engine like smarty would make things easier -->
    <section class="whole-page">
        <div class="headline-wrapper">
            <div class="headline">
                <h1></h1>
                <h2></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <div class="headline-sidewrapper">
        <div class="headline-side">
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <nav class="top-navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="boroughs.php">Boroughs</a></li>
            <li><a href="wards.php">Wards</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <aside class="sidebar"></aside>

    <section class="mainpage-wrapper">
        <!-- Dynamic page part - I recommend using a separate template that will be included here -->
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

This is a basic example using the MySQLi Database Class. I recommend you to use a template engine like [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) to make jobs like this easier. Also consider reading ['Separation of concerns'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Comment: Hi Markus, I appreciate your efforts. I downloaded the mysqlidb file and have used the code you posted above and substituted my login details but everytime I try and access that page I get a http 500 error :(

Comment: **HTTP 500 errors are _server-side_ and tell you that's something wrong with the server that is responsible for showing the requested page.** Have you got access to your server _error log files_? Try to locate them and check the last lines after loading the page in your browser. That should provide enough data to be able to find the problem cause. **Also try** a _hard refresh_ in your browser using `shift+f5` on a WIN machine or `cmd+f5 or cmd+shift+r` on a mac. This clears the browsers cache and reloads the page. Are you on a wamp or xamp setup? Make sure all _services_ are active and running

Comment: _LOL_. Used all **600** available chars in my previous comment without purpose :-P

Comment: Hi markus, thank you so much for all your efforts, I really appreciate your help. I spent another couple of hours on it today and finally figured out the problem. It was related to the mysqli_connect.php file which had a page title defined already which was overriding my variable. As soon as I deleted the head section from that file the variable worked. A simple error but due to my inexperience I only noticed today when I was viewing the source. I hope you don't feel your efforts have been wasted as I think I have learnt a lot from reviewing your answers to help avoid future problems! :)

Comment: @MWells **Glad you found out what the problem was!** If you want to give me something back for my efforts, vote my answer up and consider accepting it. I want to give you something on your way for future `debugging`of your php codes: Start using _the / a_ **php linter** that checks your code for common _mistakes_ automatically on a hit of a button or enter press in console. There a more _tools_ that help you _debug_ your codes. Also use an IDE or something like _TextMate / **SublimeText**_. It's what the _cool kids_ use out there. Check it out and give me sommin' back for it :-)